# Using multi filter datatables in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I'm trying to implement the [multiple filters](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) in the datatables in asp.net, but the time I search a value, my table is not updated.

I followed the official example of the site, but it did not work. Here is the source code I'm using.

**JS on VIEW**

```
$('#students tfoot th').each( function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                if (title !== "") {
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 100%" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
                } else {
                    $(this).html('<div class="text-center">-</div>');
                }
            } );

            tabela.columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;    
                $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keydown', function (ev) {
                    if (ev.keyCode == 13) { //only on enter keypress (code 13)
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
```

**ACTION on CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Listar2()
        {
            var search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")?[0];

            var list = db.Students;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                list = list.Where(m => m.name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || m.class.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()));
            }

            var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")?[0];
            var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start")?[0];
            var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length")?[0];

            var width = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            var skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;

            var totalRecords = list.Count();
            var resultFinal = list.Skip(skip).Take(width).ToList();

            return Json(new
            {
                data = resultFinal,
                draw,
                recordsFiltered = totalRecords,
                recordsTotal = totalRecords
            });
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for any errors? Also, there may be typo `tablela.columns` instead of `table.columns`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Yes, there is no error in the console. In addition, with each search entered, the action receives a request, but the search does not occur, because the value goes null.

Comment: I don't see any code for calling api method on entering search text. The multiple search demo url you shared is just performing client-side search on the datatable columns.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood The source code of table generator: https://gist.github.com/leomarcamargo/dc6032a5fc9c9fc9c6b528462dd539b9

Comment: @LeomardeSouza Why is your method `Listar2` and your ajax request method is `Listar`? Are you sure you are calling right method on the server?

Comment: @DipenShah Despite this, it is correct, because in the example above I simplified the source code. That's not the problem :(

Comment: @LeomardeSouza Do you see any thing in the request at all? The code is working for me without any issue.

Comment: @DipenShah yes, the request is made. However, the search is not performed, since search variable is sent with null value. Through the Request.Form I could not find a variable related to this search.

Comment: @LeomardeSouza Can you post string values in the request stream in pastebin? Just want to make sure datatable is posting data to the server.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you want to accomplish. The official example uses JavaScript to sort the datatable which is inserted into HTML already. You should load all the entries first, pass them to the view and then this script should filter those entries

Comment: I do not know what you want to accomplish The official example uses JavaScript to sort the datatable which is inserted into HTML already. You should load all the entries first, pass them to the view and then this script should filter those entries. In the comments above you have a sample link that loads the data into the view. Simple search works, but this type of multi search does not.